# Why does adding if(strlen($content)): create a syntax error with an unexpected '}'?

Tags: php

I don't see it missing an opening curly brace or not enough curly braces and yet when everything was fine until I added if(strlen($content)): $form = etcetera below. You will see some of the code commented out as I was trying to isolate the bug, but I can't understand why it throws this parse error. I don't see any missing curly brace or extra curly brace.

```
function ssp_survey_shortcode($args, $content='') {

    // setup our return variable
    $output = '';

    try {

        // begin building our output html
        $output = '<div class="ssp ssp-survey">';

        // get the survey id
        $survey_id = (isset($args['id'])) ?(int)$args['id'] : 0;

        // get the survey object
        $survey = get_post($survey_id);

        // If the survey is not a valid ssp_survey post, return a message
        if(!$survey_id || $survey->post_type !== 'ssp_survey'):

        $output.= '<p>The requested survey does not exist.</p>';

        else:

        // build form html
        $form = '';

        if(strlen($content)):
            $form = '<div class="ssp-survey-content">'.wpautop($content).'</div>';

        endif;

        $submit_button = '';

        if(!ssp_question_is_answered($survey_id)):
            $submit_button = '<div class="ssp-survey-footer">
            <p class="ssp-input-container ssp-submit">
                <input type="submit" name="ssp_submit" value="Submit Your Response" />
            </p>
            </div>';
        $form.= '<form id="survey_'.$survey_id.'" class="ssp-survey-form">'.ssp_get_question_html($survey_id).$submit_button.'</form>';
        // append form html to $output
        $output.=$form;

        endif;

        /*// close out output html div
        $output.= '</div>';*/

    } catch(Exception $e) {

        // php error
    }

    /*// return output
    return $output;*/

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like that you are missing a `endif;` in your code.

Tip, the syntax `if():endif;` is best used in template files, for only PHP code is normally used the `if(){}` sintax.

Comment: gvsrepins you nailed it. So instead of  () :, use () {, instead of endif; use } else {, correct?

Comment: @DanielCortes for only php code yes, definitely. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You missed an if. Also take a good look at your business logic. All those nested if and curly braces makes it difficult to understand the correct workflow.

```
function ssp_survey_shortcode($args, $content='') {

    // setup our return variable
    $output = '';

    try {

        // begin building our output html
        $output = '<div class="ssp ssp-survey">';

        // get the survey id
        $survey_id = (isset($args['id'])) ?(int)$args['id'] : 0;

        // get the survey object
        $survey = get_post($survey_id);

        // If the survey is not a valid ssp_survey post, return a message
        if(!$survey_id || $survey->post_type !== 'ssp_survey') {

            $output.= '<p>The requested survey does not exist.</p>';

        } else {

        // build form html
        $form = '';

        if(strlen($content)) {
            $form = '<div class="ssp-survey-content">'.wpautop($content).'</div>';

        }

        $submit_button = '';

            if(!ssp_question_is_answered($survey_id)) {
                $submit_button = '<div class="ssp-survey-footer">
                <p class="ssp-input-container ssp-submit">
                    <input type="submit" name="ssp_submit" value="Submit Your Response" />
                </p>
                </div>';
            $form.= '<form id="survey_'.$survey_id.'" class="ssp-survey-form">'.ssp_get_question_html($survey_id).$submit_button.'</form>';
            // append form html to $output
            $output.=$form;

            }
        }

        /*// close out output html div
        $output.= '</div>';*/

    } catch(Exception $e) {

        // php error
    }

    /*// return output
    return $output;*/

}
```

Comment: Kostas, your answer worked too, sorry I thought your answer was the same as gvsrepins, at any rate I am going to check it as the another correct answer because it was, both you and gvsrepins really helped out.

Comment: Not a problem at all. I 'm glad that i helped you. You can choose an answer as accepted and vote up both if you want.